# What is wrong in this code ? How to deal with IQueryable<T> anonymous type OR How to dyamically pass class to method.?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
public List<Customer> GetResult(string search, string sortOrder, int start, int length, List<Customer> dtResult, List<string> columnFilters)
        {
            return FilterResult(search, dtResult,columnFilters).SortBy(sortOrder).Skip(start).Take(length).ToList();
        }
```

> I want to convert the above code with the below code 
>   Where instead of passing  concrete class Customer I can pass T (any
>   class)

```
 public IQueryable<T> FilterResult(string search, List<T> dtresult, List<string> columnFilters)where T :class
{
    // ...  This is the function that I want to use by passing T
    // ...  **however there is some issue in this syntax**.      
}
```

I have the following class and I want to make it as reusable, but I accept that due to lack of my oops knowledge I'm facing an issue to convert this code.

```
public class ResultSet
    {
        public List<Customer> GetResult(string search, string sortOrder, int start, int length, List<Customer> dtResult, List<string> columnFilters)
        {
            return FilterResult(search, dtResult,columnFilters).SortBy(sortOrder).Skip(start).Take(length).ToList();
        }

        public int Count(string search, List<Customer> dtResult, List<string> columnFilters)
        {
            return FilterResult(search, dtResult, columnFilters).Count();
        }

        private IQueryable<Customer> FilterResult(string search, List<Customer> dtResult, List<string> columnFilters)
        {
            IQueryable<Customer> results = dtResult.AsQueryable();
           // some logic.
            return results;
        }
    }
```

> I want to make this ResultSet class as reusable by simply passing
>   anonymous class called T

Any guidance will really appreciated.

Comment: it's giving syntax error for first statement which I want to use as reusable ..

Comment: What is the meaning to convert `List` to `IQueryable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class ResultSet
{
   // public List<Customer> GetResult(string search, string sortOrder, int start, int length, List<Customer> dtResult, List<string> columnFilters)
    public List<T> GetResult<T>(string search, IQueryable<T> dtResult, List<string> columnFilters, string sortColumn, int start, int length)
    {
        // I removed the sorting here.. Use Dynamic Linq to pass sortColumn as string
        return FilterResult<T>(search, dtResult, columnFilters).Skip(start).Take(length).ToList();
    }

    public int Count<T>(string search, IQueryable<T> dtResult, List<string> columnFilters)
    {
        return FilterResult<T>(search, dtResult, columnFilters).Count();
    }

    private IQueryable<T> FilterResult<T>(string search, IQueryable<T> dtResult, List<string> columnFilters)
    {
        IQueryable<T> results = dtResult;

        // some logic.

        return results;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't make it *completely* generic because your code references properties that are *specific* to `Customer`.  If you want to use it for different *subclasses* of `Customer` you can just add that generic contraint:

```
     private IQueryable<T> FilterResult(string search, List<T> dtResult, List<string> columnFilters)
         where T: Customer
    {

        // this really does nothing (see below) but leaving it in for illustration
        IQueryable<T> results = dtResult.AsQueryable();

        .. code that references properties of `Customer` here
    }
```

Note that calling `AsQueryable` on the `List<Customer>` does nothing since the `IQueryable` extensions will see that the underlying collection is a list (and not a query) and just defer to the `IEnumerable` extension methods.

You may be under the false impression that calling `AsQueryable` will re-query your database.  That is not true since that only happens if the underlying object is a *query*.  You can't take a hydrated collection and filter it by calling back to the database.

Comment: Yes I can because it's simply passing List<class> I will take care the code logic part but the only thing I facing issue is how to make it generic .. hope you are getting me..  same way as we do in repository pattern

Comment: @user5206903 But in that method you bind to properties that are specific to the `Customer` class (`Name`, `CreditCard`, etc.) so you can't make it any more generic except for subclasses of `Customer`.  What if you passed in a `List<string>`?  What would you expect it to do when you ask for `p.Name`?

Comment: I will go by reflection  to extract the property of passed class

Comment: @user5206903 but `string` doesn't have a `Name` property, so reflection will fail - or are you intending to loop through _ALL_ properties of the class via reflection?

Comment: Then just take off the `where T: Customer` generic constraint.  Note that there's _still_ no point in calling `AsQueryable` - you could just start querying directly off of the list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90055/discussion-between-user5206903-and-d-stanley).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe not what you would like to hear, but I think things don't get better if you make this generic. The reusing of the code would only add complexity.

I would go the other way: make it more specific and therefore simpler, not more generic.

Just my 2 cents...